# DataGridViewCell PaintErrorIcon method

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I'm trying to overwrite the errorIcon of a certain column in a `DataGridView`. I've found some information about this online but the `PaintErrorIcon` method from my custom class never gets called. To test I added an override for the normal `Paint` and using the test code below I do get "PAINT" in my output, but when I set an errorText to the cells, I don't see "ERROR PAINT" (the cells DO get an error icon and Paint gets called when the error text is set).

```
public class DataGridViewWarningCell: DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
        Console.WriteLine("PAINT");
    }

    protected override void PaintErrorIcon(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellValueBounds, string errorText)
    {
        base.PaintErrorIcon(graphics, clipBounds, cellValueBounds, errorText);
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR PAINT");
    }
}
```

I've added the column to my DataGridView like this:

```
public class DataGridViewWarningColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public DataGridViewWarningColumn()
    {
        this.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewWarningCell();
    }
}
```

Then in my form code:

```
var warningColumn = new DataGridViewWarningColumn();
fileGrid.Columns.Add(warningColumn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, seems like this won't work without a little nudging..

Here is what I tried, but you will want to change the real graphics stuff, obviously..

```
protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, 
          Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, 
          object value, object formattedValue, string errorText,
          DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle 
          advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
{
    base.Paint( graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, 
                formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
     Console.WriteLine("PAINT");
     // call it by hand:
     if (errorText != "")  PaintErrorIcon(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, errorText);
}

protected override void PaintErrorIcon(Graphics graphics, 
                        Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellValueBounds, string errorText)
{
    // not the std icon, please
    //base.PaintErrorIcon(graphics, clipBounds, cellValueBounds, errorText);
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR PAINT");
    // aah, that's better ;-)
    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Fuchsia, new Rectangle( clipBounds.Right - 10,   
             cellValueBounds.Y + 3, clipBounds.Right, cellValueBounds.Height - 6));
 }
```

I have turned off `ShowCellErrors` and commented out the call to the base method.

If you can't turn off `ShowCellErrors` for the DGV you will have to take care to overpaint the standard icon completely, as it still gets drawn, even though we don't call `base.PaintErrorIcon`. Surely another symptom of something going not as expected..

I'm not sure about the best Bounds Rectangle to hand in, but it seems to do something, so that's a start..

Comment: This is what I ended up doing (was experimenting with something similar by now, but your input made it complete, thanks!)